# How do I get the first unused display in X?

Tags: python, linux, shell, xorg

How do I get the first unused X display in either Python (Don't think there's a way) or {,ba,z}sh? It could return `<number>`, `:<number>`, or `$(hostname):<number>`).

For example:

- X session at :0, 1 returned.
- X session at :0, VNC at :1, 2 returned.
- X session at :0, QEMU at :2, 1 returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no good way.  The least bad way I am aware of is to inspect the contents of `/tmp/.X11-unix`; this will contain Unix domain sockets named `X0` for `:0`, `X1` for `:1`, and so on.  If you want a TCP socket instead, attempt to connect to port 6000 and up until you get `ECONNREFUSED`.  Beware that both of these approaches have inherent race conditions which are AFAIK unfixable.

Comment: OK, it looks to be that in `/tmp/.X11-unix`, there are (lock?) files X0, X1, etc.

Comment: @tikiking1 Those are not locks, those are Unix domain sockets -- the actual communications endpoints which `libX11` will use to talk to the X server(s).  `ls -l` should have an unusual character, probably 's', in the first column of the permissions.

Comment: Would it be "safe" to use their (lack of) existence as indication of an unused display?

Comment: @tikiking1 Unfortunately no, because there's a TOCTOU race: by the time you get around to doing something with the knowledge that :N is unused, it may have become used.  This is part of why I say there is no *good* way to do this -- I'm not aware of any way to avoid the race.